# Important resources for Dark Age civilizations?

Tags: climate, natural-resources

In a time period with medieval technology, what would be the most important local resources? I've put together a small list and broken it down into categories, but I'd like to know if there's anything major I've missed.

Sustenance:

- Fresh water
- Wild game
- Fish

Minerals (Mines)

- Coal
- Iron
- Tin
- Salt
- Copper
- Lead
- Gold, Silver, and Gems

Minerals (Quarries)

- Sandstone
- Limestone
- Marble
- Granite

Natural resources

- Wood

For what it's worth, I'm putting together a medieval world generator. Image below.

[image: screenshot]

[source](https://github.com/olinkirkland/map)

Comment: Gems are utterly irrelevant. Coal had very little use in the Middle Ages. Europe has never have much gold extracted locally. And you have missed the most important resources: arable land (to grow food), wood (both to burn and to make things -- it was much more important than iron), and pasture (to grow animals, both for food and for leather and wool, other extremely important materials). Even today *a lot of stuff* is made out of wood. On the list of metals you need to add tin, to make bronze.

Comment: Gems, gold, and silver were used a lot in medieval jewelry. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medieval_jewelry

Comment: *Imported* gems and imported gold and most usually imported silver. Europe has no sources of gems, very little gold, and many European countries (e.g., England) have no silver to speak of. And jewelry is in no way an "important" -- they are small and can easily be imported.

Comment: I forgot wood! I swear it was on my list but when I was sorting things into categories it got left out. Coal was actually really important. https://riseofcoalinbritain.wordpress.com/the-high-middle-ages-1066-to-1347/

Comment: Hi, welcome to Wordbuilding.SE! If you havent, please read through our [Tour] page.

Comment: @AlexP While jewelry isn't necessarily important to survival, having a goldsmith or a silversmith in a town provides a boost to the local economy, doesn't it?

Comment: @LiamMorris Hi, thanks for the welcome. I generally just lurk.

Comment: *"A goldsmith or a silversmith in a town":* depends on what Middle Ages you are thinking of. Even the word "economy" is dubious for quite a large part of the Middle Ages. By far the largest amount of silver was used for coinage, even if coins were not really widespread things during Early and High Middle Ages; the amount of gold and silver (and, *very occasionally*, gems) used by a jewelry maker in a year can easily be carried by a person from overseas.

Comment: So a gold/silver/gem mine would not be important in a hypothetical world with medieval technology?

Comment: @OlinKirkland Not necessarily, gold, silver and gems would still be highly prized by the wealthy and well-to-do types. Spanish conquistadors famously traded with the Aztecs for these ‘worthless yellow rocks’ (also known as *gold*) as the Aztecs did not know of the value it had in other countries. This shows that gold must have had at least some measure of value, at least to the Spanish.

Comment: @OlinKirkland Thanks for the accepted answer, but it's usually good practice to leave it a day before accepting something as we've got good people in different timezones who might come up with a much better answer than mine ;)

Comment: @Ynneadwraith Didn't know! I'll do that in the future.

Comment: @OlinKirkland, you can unaccept the answer, wait and accept at a later time.

Comment: @OlinKirkland No probs ;) you can untick my answer if you like (having an answer accepted tends to discourage other people from answering somewhat). Happy if you tick it afterwards if it does turn out to be the best of course ;)

Comment: Done! :) The worldbuilding exchange definitely has a more chill vibe than the programming one.

Comment: Oh, what scale is your map? Is that a large island or a continent? We could probably hazard a guess as to where you'd get some different resources.

Comment: It's a continent. Dark forests are boreal forests. There are biomes and stuff under the hood but for stylistic reasons I'm keeping things uniform (for now).

Comment: Latitude ranges from 0 (bottom) to 90 (top)

Comment: @LiamMorris Actually, gold did not have an intrinsic value to the Spanish. While gold is an amazing material, it was expensive mainly because it was so scarce. Once you base all your economy on something that is scarce but have no intrinsic value, then that thing gets the value. The Spanish wanted gold because European (and not only European) economy was based on it.

Comment: @Sulthan I did not mean to imply gold has an intrinsic value as i am fully aware it does not have much in this context. I meant that because gold was seen as valuable to the Spanish because of the imposed value the economy put on it, they traded with the Aztecs for it. The reason gold is valuable is because it looks nice, its hard to find (but not *too* hard), can be easily shaped and is not used for anything. You can go through every material on the periodic table and only a handful would be suitable to base an economy on. Eg, copper shares many of the same properties but it is too common.

Comment: @LiamMorris I believe that multiple raw materials were used as currency through history, one of them being salt. Anything that is scarce can be used as currency.

Comment: @Sulthan That is true, Roman soliders were often paid in salt. However, salt was not valuable because it is scarce (indeed you can bucket sea water and boil off the water to get salt) it was valuable because it was useful for seasoning and preserving food and was used as a currency because it could be easily measured out. Salt could also be mined, the town i live in is home to the UK’s largest rock salt mine, it also claims to be its oldest working mine.

Comment: Definitely food and wood to advance to Feudal age.

Comment: Are we assuming the people living their brought livestock and crops with them or do they need to develop on this landmass de novo?

Comment: @John For now, as far as I want to think about it livestock spawn from settlements automatically and aren't a limited or restricted by geography

Comment: Hi Olin --- just for future reference, it's generally considered bad form in SE to choose a response as "best" so quickly.  Give it a few days to a week so you can better gauge a number of answers and so that people won't be dissuaded from writing an answer because you've already chosen your best.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @elemtilas I'll be sure to wait longer before picking an answer next time.

Comment: Glad other people have already pointed out that coal, and the precious metals are not essential at all (and in fact this is NOT the coal age, that comes later). Charcoal, which can be produced by burning wood would be enough for any blacksmith to get the high-temps needed to work metal.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In roughly descending order for a non-hunter/gatherer culture (remembering that 'medieval' doesn't just mean 'northern European':

1. Arable land/water/pasture
2. Shelter/survivable temperature/resources for clothes
3. Salt/food preservative/preservative spices (good foraging might go here too)
4. Suitable domesticated animals
5. Wood/mudbricks/wattle and daub/other simple construction material (can be replaced with hides from domesticated animals)
6. Something for cordage
7. Medicinal plants (if you have some, and perhaps I'm overblowing their importance, but a lot of people get sick in pre-modern cultures)
8. Perhaps metals/other materials for tool-making here? If they can refine iron that's pretty ubiquitous. If they need bronze then the location of tin mines would be important. And although having *something* for tools is vitally important (bone, stone etc.), it's generally quite readily available.
9. Defensibility (having big ol' mountains or raging rivers between you and the head-hunting barbarians next door is pretty valuable in a location)
10. Stone for building (not really that important. Pretty much the entirety of anglo-saxon Britain was built from wood).
11. Precious metals/non-preservative spices/other high value luxury goods (way down the list, given that you need a fair bit of the stuff above before you can start to make use of your precious metals).

I've very open to additions/repositioning, but it's a start :)

Comment: Usually, `Dark Age` starts when long-distance trade fails (`Bronze Age Collapse`, `Roman Crisis of Third Age`, `Fall of Western Roman Empire`). So, all claims like `X can be traded quite readily` are most likely false.

Comment: @user28434 True. Although what I was aiming for is steppe cultures. There have been a large number of sophisticated metal-using cultures on the Eurasian steppe without direct access to mineral ores themselves so I'm not convinced of their immediate importance. It doesn't necessarily need to be long-distance trade for iron. Bronze yes, as most of the tin for bronze in eastern Eurasia came from Britain.

Comment: @user28434 Continental-scale trade absolutely, but regional trade certainly was still taking place (just not on anywhere near the same scale). I'll edit it though with knowledge of the scale of the map.

Comment: Bronze is not really necessary once you have iron working, the materials for bronze are so rare it tends to fall out of use once people know how to make and use iron. Their are also plenty of methods for preserving food that does not rely on salt. you do have to have either metal for tools, importing basic tools was pretty rare, of course iron is ridiculously common in continental crust .

Comment: @John Good points. Iron being common is part of the reason it's so far down on the list (people would likely consider many other things before choosing somewhere on the basis of metals for toolmaking (especially if it's iron). And the other methods for preserving food thing is why I put 'salt/food preservation' ;)

Comment: Due to iron's higher melting point, it's more difficult to work with than bronze is, especially if you don't already have iron artifacts from a previously fallen civilization.  This is likely why bronze-work was invented before iron-work.

Comment: @John There are a number of applications that bronze is superior to iron for, especially early iron.

Comment: @cowlinator True, which makes it easier to discover which as you said is one of the reasons bronze was found first. Once you have discovered how to make iron though it gets a whole lot easier to make good tools, even if the process is trickier. Primarily because you don't have to ship tin 3000 nautical miles from Britain (more to the middle east).

Comment: You put salt/food preservative 3rd, but spices last. Yet spices were often used as food preservatives. That used to be the driving force behind most of the Spice Isles trade and an important factor in trade for most tropical civilisations. As we do not know the culture OP's is using as a template, your point two is very eurocentric.

Comment: @TheDyingOfLight Very good point indeed about spices. I'll swap that around. The shelter thing, however, is broad enough to cover the majority of the world's cultures. Anywhere the temperature gets down to below 12 degrees people will need shelter of come variety. Anywhere the temperature gets hotter than we can usually cope with naturally is the same. Same goes for constant heavy rainfall or tropical storms or most severe weather. Anything else falls under the 'survivable temperature' bit :)

Comment: @Ynneadwraith Why did you mention shelter in the tropics? I never criticised that point. Was that comment for me? I'm confused... . Also adding "workable stones" to the metal category could be good, as there where a number of civilisations in rhe middle ages, which still used non-metal tools. Think Inuit (bone tools) and the Mesoamericans, Inca and Pacific civilisations, which used stone and wood tools.

Comment: @TheDyingoftheLight Ah, the tropical shelter bit was a justification for number 2 not being eurocentric :) very good point about alternative tool materials. I'll edit that in :)

Answer (score 11):

### Flax

Flax is a plant that was often farmed in Medieval and Pre-Medieval societies around the world. It was an important resource to many societies for several reasons:

**Food**

Firstly, its seeds can be turned into a meal or used for linseed oil, a finishing used on wood to protect it from weathering or it can be injested as it too can be edible. The meal produced can be eaten, used as feed for livestock or ground into flour to make bread.

**Linen**

Perhaps the most useful use of flax was to create linen, a textile. This could be used to make clothing, bedding and pratically anything that cotton can make, flax can make too. A huge feature of linen though is its ability to produce extremely protective armour. By layering pieces of linen, you can create a gambeson, a type of armour used by both rich and poor for its protective value.

**String**

*Because flax is string*. Flax is used to make string, even today, by twisting the fibres of the plant together. As you can imagine, string is highly useful for temporarily holding things together. You can also keep twisting the fibres together until you get rope, which can be even more useful if you need larger, heavier objects holding in place, such as a ship or drawbridge.

**Other Uses**

The same fibres used to make string can instead be used to make canvas, slightly less useful but can be highly valuable with paint on them. It can also be used to make paper, flooring, inks, paints or just be grown as a decorative plant.

Supposedly its specific epithet, usitatissum, means “most useful”. The plant has been cultivated since at least Ancient Egyptian times and has been grown all over Europe and Asia for its numerous uses.

Comment: side note, you can likely buy flax seed at your local supermarket as a cheap food additive

Comment: Note if they are bringing livestock and crops with them they could easily bring a cordage crop like flax or hemp, cordage was usually farmed not collected wild.

Comment: @John True, i thought that i was implying it was farmed in my answer, i will edit it to make that clearer. However, it does not change the answer, flax was still a highly valuable resource, hence *why* it was farmed to get more of it.

Comment: A gambeson is quilted and often of wool, so perhaps you are thinking of the linothorax (iconic armor of hoplites)? That is specifically referring to laminated layers of linen. Obviously a gambeson could be called layered linen, but quilted cloth is a more accurate description for it.

Comment: @pluckedkiwi No, i’m fairly certain i am refering to gambeson, they too consisted of layers of linen. The layers also sometimes had wool sewn in between if that is what you are referring to. Here is where i got my information: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-uWDCDJD_4w

Comment: @LiamMorris as I said, a gambeson could be called "layered linen", but I find layered to be a weird way of describing something that was quilted as they have much different connotations of construction to me. Your description also seems to imply that gambesons are specifically made of linen, when it is just whatever cloth was handy (which was often linen but there is no inherent connection between linen and a gambeson).

Comment: @pluckedkiwi Ah, i see what you mean now, i thought you were rejecting the idea that gambesons could be made of linen. Yes, whislt it could likely be made out of almost any cloth or cloth-like material, they were often made of linen because they had alot of it on-hand and were producing it anyway. For that reason, in my mind, gambesons are associated with linen, as thats what they were most often made of. Its a similar association with steel and swords, swords could be made out of iron or bronze but in my mind, they are most associated with steel unless otherwise specified.

Comment: Note that flax isn't the only efficient way to get fibers for ropes and cloth. In Polynesia a number of trees were used to gain strong fibers for ropes, another ones gave some cloth equivalent, u.s.w.

Answer (score 6):

Most of your list is irrelevant. You need the big three and maybe two more things. The first and last thought in your head has to be FARMS, farming is everything, it is the source that supports everything else in the society and most of your population will be farmers. If it it not used on a farm it will not have much use.

Drinkable **water**

**arable land**

A robust supply of **lumber**

Assuming the people bring crops and livestock with them. Everything else is a product of these three things, or incidental and not really required.  Ideally there would some **clay** and **iron** deposits as well but these tend to exist everywhere that has the above. Of course you also need **crops** and a **livestock** but people tend to bring those with them. Farming is the basis of society it supports everything else and the majority of your population will be farmers. Regular rain will be important if people can't farm they are not going to live there.

water is self explanatory, rivers and ground-water can supply that. Arable land is the basis for food, hunting occurs but it is not a huge focus of society. Wood is the basis for all technology tools, homes, cooking, all are wood resources, even the charcoal used for metalworking is made from wood. the few things that cannot be made of wood are usually made of clay or a metal usually iron or copper. A naturally occurring plant useful for **cordage** like hemp or linen may be helpful, but people will farm these plants as well.

Some other things would be nice to have but they are by no means necessary, **fishable waters, source of salt (either mines or bays), good harbors, limestone**, these are nice but my no means necessary. Stone is used when available, but is generally too labor intensive to get much use.

If you want to get an idea of what life would be like There is a great BBC series available online called, **[the tudor farm](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dRj1YYnsBGk)** that is about a group of experimental archeologists and historians recreating a Stuart farm and living there for a year. It can give you a great idea of what is really needed for civilization of that time.  A later program by the same people is about building a castle using all period techniques, (secrets of the castle) and you will notice that even there the only other resource they use is occasionally lead and chalk. Shapeable stone like granite or sandstone are nice but only really necessary if you want to have stone buildings it is not necessary. you tend to have some source of stone anyway, arable land needs a mineral source to refresh soil which is usually nearby mountains.

Tin, coal, precious metals, gems, and marble are more or less useless in such a society, or so hard to use or get that they are only used for expensive showy non-essential uses. They may be used if available but they are by no means necessary.

Comment: Great answer, and clear in the priority of resources, but it's a little northern-European centric. Eurasian steppe nomads have continually produced sophisticated cultures throughout recorded history without relying on arable land or farming. Change it to 'arable land/pasture for livestock' and you have my vote ;) Oh, they have also done so without ready supply of wood, so I'm not convinced that is a solid requirement either.

Comment: Dark age technology does not say steppe nomads to me, the dark ages was a european occurrence, a time and a place. Specifically eastern europe after the fall of the roman empire.  Also even the steppe people needed quite a lot of timber, there migratory patterns always included forests.

Comment: True, although I really do struggle with that cultural perception. The level of technological development in the Dark Ages was roughly similar throughout Western Eurasia so the relatively arbitrary exclusion of steppe nomads seems bizarre to me. It's something that flags 'undeveloped worldbuilding' to me if people are basing things heavily on medieval Europe on the scale that should heavily involve steppe nomads...and for some reason doesn't. Good point about forests though, hadn't spotted that ;)

Comment: If the OP had said medieval civilization I would use a much broader set, including the Chinese, Callifates, as well as the steppe peoples. More likely would have asked for the OP to narrow it down a bit to what type of culture they were looking for and then gone from there, Dark ages is pretty narrow medieval is not.

Comment: @John To me "Dark Ages" means the eastern Mediterranean and Middle East in 12th and 11th century BC until the rise of the Neo-Hittites in the 10th century BC. That is when history went dark post-collapse as writing largely disappeared and we know very little. What the OP probably meant was Northern Europe in the Migration or Early Medieval period (which is hardly "dark" to me as we know lots about it). As for the fall of the Roman empire, when exactly was that? 1453?

Comment: And just a quick commentary on the linked farm documentary - that is of a 17th century farm, which is about 800 years too recent for the OP. The same people also do a Tudor monastery farm (highly recommended), which is much closer in time, but still hundreds of years after anything which could be called dark ages.

Comment: Good point about the tudor farm is a better fit for the time period.

Answer (score 5):

Arguably, the most imporant resource was land.

Arable land provided a way for the local lords to gain economic power: by providing protection for the local populace in exchange for food and good that they produced. Whilst the food itsef is not likely to make them a fortune, they would not be able to make the money if they and their men were starved half to death constantly. Land was often given to wealth lords or knights by the ruler as a reward for various things.

Even non-arable land would have some uses, such as being ideal to build upon as you would not need to worry about losing out on useful, farmable land. You might also be able to house animals on there, assuming you have some way of feeding them.

Additionally, hills and mountains would be highly valued for their defensibility. Castles and fortresses were often built on them where possible in order to have a staging point and fortified poition in case of an attack. This also allows for you to defend other resources that you own, such as forrests, quarries, rivers etc.

Access to coastlines and large rivers was also extremely important. If you have access to the sea, not only do you have a source of fish for your local population, you can create docks and ports to allow for trade with other regions or even other nations. Alternatively, having sea access meant you could defend your country from invasions via ships, intercepting them before they landed.

Alternatively, you could argue that the most important resource was people. Without the backs of labourers, the hands of artisans and the swords of soliders, the lords, and indeed countries, would not be able to gain the wealth and influence that they had and nothing would ever get done.

Answer (score 0):

Good points all and valid.

Civilisations of the past have failed when they outgrew their local resources, usually wood in the limit as it is impractical to transport over large distances.

However you show a medieval island that is small if the features that look like mountains are mountains.

So the most important requirement is a human gene pool.  There are various theories and numbers that are bandied about, but in the end you need to have enough people and enough land to feed them.  A small island nation will not survive indefinitely with a fenced population.

Comment: I think that those mountainous stuctures are meant to be mountain *ranges* rather than just individual mountains. Addimittedly, they are still rather large considering the scale but perhaps that is a limitation of the medium. If they were to scale, they might be so small on that map that you would not be able to see them, hence making them substantially larger.